# GNU make: Timing a build, is it possible to have a target whose recipe executes after all targets complete

Tags: gnu-make

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772393/gnu-make-run-a-target-after-all-others-regardless-of-failures) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082553/recursive-make-q-generic-target-after-other-targets).

In essence, something like the following is what I'm looking for -- or a fairly clean hack for pulling it off:

```
GET_TIMESTAMP  = $(shell perl -e 'print time()')
START_TIME    := ${GET_TIMESTAMP}

all: T1 T2 ... TN

T1:
T2:
...:
TN:

#...

timer:
  @perl -e 'printf( "Loaded makefiles in %ds, build completed in %ds\n", $ARGV[1] - $ARGV[0], $ARGV[2] - $ARGV[1] );' ${START_TIME} ${LOAD_COMPLETE} ${GET_TIMESTAMP}

.ATEND: timer

LOAD_COMPLETE := ${GET_TIMESTAMP}
```

... which could be kicked off in a number of ways:

```
~ gmake all
(...)
  Loaded makefiles in 8s, build completed in 93s
~ gmake T2 T3 T4
(...)
  Loaded makefiles in 8s, build completed in 13s
```

At the heart of it is this idea of an `.ATEND` special target that causes something to happen when all `CMDGOALS` or `DEFAULTGOALS` are finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution just occurred to me for this:

```
GET_TIMESTAMP  = $(shell perl -e 'print time()')
START_TIME    := ${GET_TIMESTAMP}

all: T1 T2 ... TN

T1:
T2:
...:
TN:

timer_target : ${TIMER_DEPENDENCY}
  @echo do whatever to print out timing info
```

This would be used from the command line as:

```
gmake timer_target TIMER_DEPENDENCY='T3 T4 T5'
```

... or something similar.

It won't work for every target seamlessly, but it's usable.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to time your build, and you're running on a UNIXy platform, why not just use `time` itself?

As in:

```
pax$ time sleep 1
    real    0m1.004s
    user    0m0.000s
    sys     0m0.000s
```

(although, in your case, it would of course be `time gmake all`).

This seems a much more elegant solution than trying to code something up in `make` and uses the right tools for the job.

---

Alternatively, you could modify the rule itself to be something like:

```
all: T1 T2 ... TN
    @perl -e blah blah blah
```

This will ensure the Perl is executed once all targets are complete - you'll have to fiddle with the `makefile` so it's not an automatic solution (you'll be best off limiting yourself to certain high-level targets), but I don't think that's a huge burden since makefiles tend to be *relatively* changeless once set up correctly.

Comment: +1 because it *is* a viable alternative.  I wanted it built-in so you would always have the facility available without having to use an extra tool, but this is certainly a decent alternative if nothing else is available.  Part of the custom solution was being able to time how long it takes to parse all the makefiles, but I may have to settle for command-line tools and a custom target for timing stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Well I have been wondering the same for a while, and tried a few things.
I guess a recursive make might do it, but I avoid those so far.
Pity there isn't a .ATEND indeed!

Note: Obviously you will only show how long re-made recipes take, unless from a clean.

### time

So as paxdiablo suggested unix time commmand is the easiest (and what I have done in the past).

```
% time make
```

### recipe based

Adding a timer to each recipe will give you a cumulative run time, but not an idea of how long each recipe took (not that it was in the question).
However for specific recipes you could make use of time again within the recipe and even tee the output to a logfile (using pipefail in bash). eg

```
# SHELL = /bin/bash -o pipefail
# @bash -o pipefail -c ' ( time /home/matt/bin/example_stdouterr.bash ) |& tee z.log'
# @bash -o pipefail -c ' ( time /home/matt/bin/example_stdouterr.bash ) 2>&1 | tee z.log '
```

### summary

So I think just adding it to most of the recipes would be the best.
You don't need a special call then.
See below for an example, which should show differences with:

```
time -p make 
time -p make -j 2
```

### Example

Gives cumulative time, as well as timestamp.

```
TIME_START := $(shell date +%s)
define TIME-END
@time_end=`date +%s` ; time_exec=`awk -v "TS=${TIME_START}" -v "TE=$$time_end" 'BEGIN{TD=TE-TS;printf "%02dd:%02dh:%02dm:%02ds\n",TD/(60*60*24),TD/(60*60)%24,TD/(60)%60,TD%60}'` ; echo "##DATE end   `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'` cumulative $${time_exec} $@"
endef

PHONY_GOALS := all
all: toprule1
    $(TIME-END)

PHONY_GOALS += toprule1
toprule1: subrule1 subrule2
    @echo toprule 1 start
    @sleep 1
    @echo toprule 1 done
    $(TIME-END)

PHONY_GOALS += subrule1
subrule1: botrule1
    @echo subrule 1 start
    @sleep 1
    @echo subrule 1 done
    $(TIME-END)

PHONY_GOALS += subrule2
subrule2: botrule1
    @echo subrule 2 start
    @time -p sleep 2
    @echo subrule 2 done
    $(TIME-END)

PHONY_GOALS += botrule1
botrule1:
    @echo botrule 1 start
    @sleep 1
    @echo "botrule 1 done"
    $(TIME-END)

PHONY_GOALS += help
help:
    @echo "$(info All the goals are: ${PHONY_GOALS})"

########### end bit
.PHONY :${PHONY_GOALS}
OTHER_GOALS := ${filter-out ${PHONY_GOALS}, ${MAKECMDGOALS}}
${OTHER_GOALS}:
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just had a thought, and coded it.
You can have a timer goal that has prerequisites for any other command goals or all if empty. Then it would just be:

```
make -j 2 subrule1 timer
```

Example below (oh it also does elapsed timer as long as it is on same recipe line).

```
# gnu make file

TIME_START := $(shell date +%s)
define TIME-END
@time_end=`date +%s` ; \
 time_exec=`awk -v "TS=${TIME_START}" -v "TE=$$time_end" 'BEGIN{TD=TE-TS;printf "%02dd:%02dh:%02dm:%02ds\n",TD/(60*60*24),TD/(60*60)%24,TD/(60)%60,TD%60}'` ; \
 echo "##DATE end   `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'` cumulative $${time_exec} $@"
endef

define ELAPSED-START
@elapsed_start=`date +%s`
endef
define ELAPSED-END
elapsed_end=`date +%s` ; \
 elapsed_exec=`awk -v "TS=$$elapsed_start" -v "TE=$$elapsed_end" 'BEGIN{TD=TE-TS;printf "%02dd:%02dh:%02dm:%02ds\n",TD/(60*60*24),TD/(60*60)%24,TD/(60)%60,TD%60}'` ; \
 echo "##DATE end   `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'` elapsed $${elapsed_exec} $@"
endef

PHONY_GOALS := all
all: subrule1 subrule2
    @$(TIME-END)

PHONY_GOALS += subrule1
subrule1: 
    $(ELAPSED-START) ; \
    echo subrule 1 start ; \
    sleep 1 ; \
    echo subrule 1 done ; \
    $(ELAPSED-END)
    @sleep 1
    @$(TIME-END)

PHONY_GOALS += subrule2
subrule2: 
    @echo subrule 2 start
    @$(ELAPSED-START) ; time -p sleep 2 ; $(ELAPSED-END)
    @echo subrule 2 done
    @$(TIME-END)

# create a prereq for timer to any CMDGOAL if empty add all
TIMERPREREQ := ${filter-out timer, ${MAKECMDGOALS}}
ifeq ($(strip $(TIMERPREREQ)),)
TIMERPREREQ := all
endif
#$(info TIMERPREREQ := ${TIMERPREREQ})

PHONY_GOALS += timer
timer: ${TIMERPREREQ}
    @$(TIME-END)

PHONY_GOALS += help
help:
    @echo "$(info All the goals are: ${PHONY_GOALS})"

########### end bit
.PHONY :${PHONY_GOALS}
```

Result  is:

```
subrule 1 start
subrule 1 done
##DATE end   2016-03-18 13:41:56 GMT elapsed 00d:00h:00m:01s subrule1
##DATE end   2016-03-18 13:41:57 GMT cumulative 00d:00h:00m:02s subrule1
##DATE end   2016-03-18 13:41:58 GMT cumulative 00d:00h:00m:02s timer
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this tiny solution in a make system that couldn't be modified (Makefiles were read only).

Save this file as "timebash" and set execute permissions on it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# shell replacement to time make recipes, invoke with:
#    make SHELL='/path/to/timebash "$(@)"' . . .
# timing data (start, elapsed) appears in the make output, along
# with a "make stack" tracked in the MKSTACK variable like
#    "target[0].subtarg[1].subtarg2[2]..."
target="$1"
shift
export MKSTACK
MKSTACK="${MKSTACK}${MKSTACK:+.}${target}[$MAKELEVEL]"

# compose your timing data format here
# on multiple lines here for readability
now=$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
fmt="timebash:$$"                ## each line starts with 'timebash'+pid
fmt="${fmt}:mkstack=${MKSTACK}"  ## add the MKSTACK
fmt="${fmt}:start=${now}"        ## wall clock at start
fmt="${fmt}:elapsed=%e"          ## time() fills this in
fmt="${fmt}:cmd='%C'"            ## time() fills this too

# now invoke time and the original make command
/usr/bin/time -f "$fmt" -- /bin/bash "${@}"
```

Then you can invoke make like this without changing any Makefiles

```
make SHELL='/path/to/timebash "$(@)"' . . .
```

I wrote a python script to render the timing data in an ascii gantt chart and was able to visualize the make timing quite clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you like this Makefile performance measuring tool.
This script works with ALL versions and brands of make.

For my own use I wrote this Python helper script to maintain Makefile elapsed timings externally.  It works very well and is fairly well documented.

Using this script unloads a complex and subtle task from the 'make' utility and enables the Makefile writer to exercise fine-grained control over reporting of make performance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
MakeTime.py(support)
NAME
    MakeTime.py - Maintain storage for Makefile rule elapsed times.
SYNOPSIS
    MakeTime.py [OPTION]
    MakeTime.py [label] [title text]
DESCRIPTION
    Hold timing data in the external file 'MakeTime.json'.
OPTIONS
    -c, --clean, --clear, --initialize
        Delete the external file.

    -s, --summary, --summarize, --report
        Generate summary of stored timing data.

    -h, --help, (anything else beginning with '-')
        Show this help

EXAMPLES
    ./MakeTime.py
    ./MakeTime.py -h
    ./MakeTime.py --help
        Show help

    ./MakeTime.py -c
    ./MakeTime.py --clean
    ./MakeTime.py --clear
    ./MakeTime.py --initialize
        Delete JSON file 'MakeTime.json' to prepare for new timings.

    ./MakeTime.py START How much time does the make execution take?
        Associate title and t0 for START rule

    ./MakeTime.py START
        Associate t1 to JSON for START rule

    ./MakeTime.py -r
    ./MakeTime.py -s
    ./MakeTime.py --report
    ./MakeTime.py --summary
    ./MakeTime.py --summarize
        Perform calculations for execution times then
        summarize collected timings with labels to help.


EXAMPLE MAKEFILE
###############################################################################
all:    START rule1 rule2 END

.PHONY:
START:
    @./MakeTime.py --clear
    @./MakeTime.py $@ Elapsed during the entire make process.

.PHONY:
rule1:
    @./MakeTime.py $@ Elapsed during rule1.
    sleep 3
    @./MakeTime.py $@

.PHONY:
rule2:
    @./MakeTime.py $@ Elapsed during rule2.
    sleep 5
    @./MakeTime.py $@

.PHONY:
END:
    @./MakeTime.py START
    @./MakeTime.py --summary
###############################################################################

COPYRIGHT
    Copyright(c)2016 Jonathan D. Lettvin, All Rights Reserved
"""

from time import time
from sys import argv
from pprint import pprint
from os import remove
from os.path import exists

store = "MakeTime.json"
result = {}
marked = time()


if len(argv) == 1:
    "When no args are given, display the help text."
    print __doc__

elif len(argv) == 2:
    arg1 = argv[1]

    if arg1 in ["-c", "--clean", "--clear", "--initialize"]:
        "Clear the backstore."
        if exists(store):
            remove(store)

    elif arg1 in ["-r", "-s", "--summary", "--summarize", "--report"]:
        "Calculate elapsed times and print summary"
        with open(store, "r") as source:
            names = []
            seen = set()
            for n, line in enumerate(source):
                data = eval(line)
                for k,v in data.iteritems():
                    result[k] = result.get(k, {})
                    result[k].update(v)
                    if not k in seen:
                        seen.add(k)
                        names.append(k)
        for k in names:
            v = result[k]
            timing = "unknown MakeTime"
            if v.has_key('t1') and v.has_key('t0'):
                timing = "%4.3f seconds" % (float(v['t1']) - float(v['t0']))
            print("\t\t%s [%s] %s" % (timing, k, v['title']))

    elif arg1[0] == '-':  # -, -h, --help, or anything beginning with '-'
        print __doc__

    else:
        "Per rule delta"
        result = {arg1: {'t1': marked}}
        with open(store, "a") as target:
            print>>target, str(result)

else:
    "Per rule t0"
    result = {argv[1]: {'t0': marked, 'title': " ".join(argv[2:])}}
    with open(store, "a") as target:
        print>>target, str(result)
```